# What is the best way to deploy Thrift Java service implementations?

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, soa, thrift

I know Thrift has its own Threadpool server but I'm not sure it will be able to handle heavy load. Would you recommend putting it behind tomcat ?
In addition, if you wanted to use the socket transport implementation could you still use tomcat ? or would need to use some other solution ?
I would really love to hear about your experience deploying thrift java services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider putting it inside application server (tomcat, jetty, etc.) and accessing it through HTTP using [TServlet](http://people.apache.org/~jfarrell/thrift/0.6.1/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/server/TServlet.html). You get from the server:

1. Threads management
2. Connections management
3. You get to use standard `Filter`s to maybe rate limit the requests, or manage access based on cookies
4. Probably readily available access logs
5. You can easily add JSON Protocol for debugging

Comment: Good scalability advice. But default non-embedded implementation of simple binary protocol will work faster I think.

Comment: any advice if I want to use socekts ? would tomcat (or any other app server)support that ?

Comment: You can use sockets inside an application server, but there is not much point - you will still have to manage them manually. The application server will only handle the HTTP requests. And I don't think it'll be much slower, if you don't need ultra low-latency, go with HTTP. Test the differences in speed if in doubt.